# Trying to upload files to the server with PHP but it's always converted as .jpg format

Tags: php

i'm trying to make an upload files function which allowing users to upload images, videos, and compressed files (.rar) and auto renamed the file in case to prevent files uploaded with the same name and replacing each others.

But when i'm trying to upload it one by one, everything uploaded is converted to `.jpg` format.

Can someone help me please ?

This is my script :

```
function reArrayFiles(&$file_post) {

$file_ary = array();
$file_count = count($file_post['name']);
$file_keys = array_keys($file_post);

for ($i=0; $i<$file_count; $i++) {
    foreach ($file_keys as $key) {
        $file_ary[$i][$key] = $file_post[$key][$i];
    }
}

return $file_ary;
}


if ($_FILES['upload']) {
    $file_ary = reArrayFiles($_FILES['upload']);

foreach ($file_ary as $file) {
  echo "<p>";
    print 'File Name: ' . $file['name'] . '<br />';
    print 'File Type: ' . $file['type'] . '<br />';
    print 'File Size: ' . $file['size'] . '<br />';
    print 'File Temp: ' . $file['tmp_name'] . '<br />';
  echo "</p>";

  if ($file['type'] == 'jpg' || 'jpeg') {
    $newname = date('YmdHis',time()).mt_rand().'.jpg';
    $dir = 'upload/images/'.$newname;
    move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $dir);
  }

  if ($file['type'] == 'mp4') {
    $newname_video = date('YmHis',time()).mt_rand().'.mp4';
    $dir2          = 'upload/videos/'. $newname_video;
    move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $dir2);
  }

  if ($file['type'] == 'rar') {
    $newname_other = date('YmHis',time()).mt_rand().'.rar';
    $dir3          = 'upload/others/'. $newname_other;
    move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $dir3);
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`if ($file['type'] == 'jpg' || 'jpeg') {`

is evaluated as if it were:

`if (($file['type'] == 'jpg') || ('jpeg')) {`

and a non-empty string evaluates to true so this if always passes.

Change it to:

`if (($file['type'] == 'jpg') || ($file['type'] == 'jpeg')) {`

and it should work as expected.

Comment: does i have to change all of those similar script or just the jpg and jpeg(s) one sir ?

when i change only the first condition, it works like a charm, but when i change all of them, it doesn't uploading the file

Comment: @DonnyK.Pratama Only if they have items separated by `||` or `or`. In the sample code you listed, only jpg/jpeg had that problem. In general, I tend to use more parentheses than necessary in order to make 100% sure that evaluation is as expected. There are sometimes variations in operator precedence in different languages, plus using parentheses even when not absolutely necessary can result in more readable code. But in this case they **are** necessary to make the code work properly.

Comment: Thanks for the solution sir, but something's wrong happened here, it was working once but when i'm trying to upload more files, it does not uploading anymore.. do you know why is this happened, sir ? honestly, i'm a beginner at programming.. xD

Comment: @DonnyK.Pratama - Sorry, can't guess what might have changed. You will need to post updated code and any specific errors.

Comment: oh okay.. allright than, thanks a lot for the help sir.. :D